# Failure to log in /var/log using Winston Logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I have been trying for over 10 hours to find a way of utilizing Winston to log in my /var/log directory on my fedora system but it does not work.

I made a project using express just to test Winston and when i tried logging on my project directory it works fine but when it comes to logging in anywhere starting with '~' or '/' it does not create the file or log and no error or exception is thrown, please any help would be appreciated.

I have gone through several forums and found out that its a regular problem but i have not seen a current one, so i want to know if there is a solution.

Comment: winston doesn't throw errors, it `emit`s them, so you should be able to get your errors with `.on('error', console.error)`. And `~` is a value specific to certain terminals such as Bash. `fs` doesn't know about it.

Comment: @LucasS. Thank you, i would try using that to see if i can get any significant error to know how to debug.

Comment: @LucasS. How do i implement the .on('error', console.error)?

I have something like this
var logger = createLogger({}).on('error', console.error);

Comment: I'm not sure if `.on` returns the logger instance, so you should do it on separate lines: `var logger = winston.createLogger({}); logger.on('error', err => /* do something */);`

Answer (score 2):

How to work `Winston` logger if we provide a file path to write log, it will search for that file in the mentioned directory if not exists then will create with the same name.

But in  *~/*  type of directory in Unix system permission requires to write something. If your console that thrown error you will get that error stack like below for sure :

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open \'/var/log/your.log\
```

The solution is: you can create a file in `/var/log/your.log` file and then give permission to write. `sudo chmod a+w /var/log/your.log`.

> Yes it will work fine into your project directory here any write is allowed, That's why.

Comment: Thanks Osman, i thought of this as an approach but this project should be able to create the file automatically if it does not exist, a manual approach of creating the files is not the intent

Comment: Yeah I know it's not the intent, that permission into dir or the specific folder for the user you can enable. But I told you the reason and workaround. If you are able to change permission things in the machine then it's better.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your statement and advice but that is not the direction we are thinking of because we do not want to have to create a file and have write access to it on every system where the app is being deployed, we are looking at writing to the temp folder or an easily accessible consistent location and i am yet to find the way to view what prevents it from writing to be sure that its lack of access and from that i can know where to go

Answer (score 1):

I came to the conclusion as the stackoverflow user *Osman Goni Nahid* mentioned/advised that the best way around is to create a file manually, change the permissions of that file to have access and then write to it in code because if winston does not have permissions to a folder, it just runs the other process and does not create or write to the file, in my case i went for a better accessible location where reading and writing was accessible so i could still maintain my automatic creation of file because that was key in my project.

Thank you  *Lucas S*  and *Osman Goni Nahid* for your advice!!